# How to Remove/Replace Alfresco from Java application with Drupal or Drupal plugin?

Tags: java, drupal, alfresco

OK, here are some more details. I need to remove/replace Alfresco from a Java application, the content that Alfresco manages is some HTML and some PDFs. My team wants to move the content to a remote website that runs with Drupal.

So is there a supported way to have my Java application retrieve the content from alfresco and move it to Drupal? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 8 provides [RESTful Web Services](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/rest) which you can use to retrieve data from the Drupal site into your Java application. A similar feature exists for Drupal 7 with the [RESTful module](https://www.drupal.org/project/restful).

You also have the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module, available for both Drupal 8 and 7 and providing a different Web Service interface

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to permanently remove Alfresco from your solution. To do that, you'll need to export the HTML and PDFs out of the Alfresco repository and make those available to Drupal. As mitpatoliya suggests, there are multiple approaches to getting the files out of Alfresco, including FTP and WebDAV. You could also use OpenCMIS to write a little Java application that will grab the files out of Alfresco and write them somewhere.

It's not clear from your question whether or not your Alfresco objects have custom metadata. If they do, and Drupal needs to know about it, you'll need more than the binary files exported out of Alfresco. You'll also need property values from those objects. The advantage to using OpenCMIS to do the export is that you can use it to read the metadata stored about the files and then write that to a CSV or some other format for loading into Drupal.

Now that you have all of the files and potentially metadata copied out of Alfresco you need to import that into Drupal. But Drupal's model is completely different from Alfresco, so how you do that will depend very much on how your Drupal site was built. Your binary files might not go into Drupal at all but will instead be served up as static assets, for example. Or you might need to take some of that metadata you exported out of Alfresco and create Drupal nodes.

If you need to create those Drupal nodes programmatically and you have to use Java, you might want to look at Drupal's [RESTful](https://www.drupal.org/project/restful) module and just use an HTTP client from your Java code to make calls against endpoints that create the nodes. But there are many ways to go about this.

Comment: Moving the data from Alfresco to Drupal is not a problem. My only problem is making my Java application retrieve data from Drupal. Note: by this point I hope to use Alfresco at all, I need to completely stop using Alfresco.

Comment: In that case, I'd remove references to Alfresco from your original question as well as the "alfresco" tag and re-phrase the question more along the lines of using a Java application to manage content in Drupal.

Comment: I guess I should, Sorry about being misleading. I will rewrite my question, thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have some HTML and PDF files which are stored in alfresco and you do not want to pull any metadata then you can just get all your contents from alfresco via FTP or Webdev and then dump it to your Drupal site.

There are Alfresco Drupal connector available but It is not required in your case because you just want to migrate data one time right?

Comment: I don't want to keep Alfresco around anymore, I want to completely remove Alfresco  from my Java application and move the content (HTML and PFDs) to the remote Drupal website. I am having a hard time making my Java application to retrieve the content from Drupal. Does that make more sense!?